# JavaScriptで単語一致

Tags: javascript

複数の文字列のいずれかにマッチするパターンを記述する
https://www.javadrive.jp/javascript/regexp/index12.html

このサイトを参考にしたところ、求めていることが出来たのですが、検索する単語をローカルストレージに保存して、呼び出そうとすると失敗してしまいます。

```
var SearchWord = /hoge/;
localStorage.setItem("key", SearchWord);
var SearchWord = localStorage.getItem("key");
console.log(SearchWord.test('TesthogeTest'));
```

`VM213:4 Uncaught TypeError: SearchWord.test is not a function`

```
var SearchWord = /hoge/;
console.log(SearchWord.test('TesthogeTest'));
```

`true`

どのようにすれば良いでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`localStorage`の説明](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#%E8%AA%AC%E6%98%8E)に

> `localStorage` に保存されるキーと値は常に UTF-16 文字列 (1 文字に 2 バイトを使用する) になります。オブジェクトと同様に、整数のキーは自動的に文字列に変換されます。

とあるように文字列に変換されます。

> ```
> var SearchWord = /hoge/;
> localStorage.setItem("key", SearchWord);
> ```

において `SearchWord` は文字列でなく[`RegExp`オブジェクト](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)ですから文字列化されることを意識する必要があります。

```
var SearchWord = /hoge/;
localStorage.setItem("key", SearchWord.source);
var SearchWord = new RegExp(localStorage.getItem("key"));
```